# check if substring exists in main string per word

Tags: javascript

I have a string I want to check if a substring is in the main string. The code I have below works partially. The problem is I want to check if the substring matches per word to the main string currently it checks per character. To Explain this better say my main string is `the banana is yellow` and if the substring I am looking for is `banana is` I want it to print true but if the substring is `ana is` it prints false. How can I achieve this?

```js
const testString = 'the banana is yellow'
const checkString = 'ana is'

//should have printed false
if (testString.includes(checkString)) {
  console.log('true')
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
```

Comment: @Dai nope just edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn the needle into a regular expression surrounded by word boundaries.

```js
const testString = 'the banana is yellow'
const checkString = 'ana is'
const pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + checkString + '\\b');

console.log(pattern.test(testString));
```

If the needle might contain special characters, [escape them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) before passing to the RegExp constructor.

Comment: Why escape special characters? check string ```banana i*s``` would reply false.

Comment: @seriously because you want all the characters of `checkString` to be matched literally, and not to be interpreted as any special regular expression syntax.

Comment: Escape the special characters if you would want that to be detected a match (and the special characters aren't on the edge of the needle)